# Automating creating a sequence of variable in Big query using loops

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to automate the creation of variables till the maximum number of id -values are present

[image]

Comment: Show the code you have done so far?

Comment: I don't know how to do this in Bigquery

Comment: above snapshot is an example where I have Id & base values(Column A) with me and with that I want to create st variables by multiplying Col A value with previous row col A

Comment: not clear! please update your question with more details, examples